# How did Weyland-Yutani already know about the warning beacon on LV-426 before the events of Alien?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

It's obvious from Special Order 937 that Weyland-Yutani had somehow already detected the warning beacon emanating from the derelict on LV-426, and had at least partially deciphered it. Is it ever explained anywhere *how* and *when* they managed to pick up the signal and decipher it? I've always assumed that the events of *Alien* were the first time humans had ever encountered the xenomorphs and that Weyland-Yutani knew very little about them other than that they were dangerous. I've also wondered if the company always knew immediately that it wasn't a distress signal, as any ship passing by before the *Nostromo* would have been required to investigate it, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

According to the viral website ProjectPrometheus.com (transcribed below from [yutani.studio](https://yutani.studio/2018/01/18/quiet-eye/)), Weyland Yutani discovered a faint signal emanating from LV-426 as part of their deep space exploration, likely in 2078 or 2079. It was one of the reasons that Peter Wayland authorised a trip to LV-223, a nearby planet in the same system. They presumably (partially) deciphered it at much the same time.

> As fate would have it, Shaw and Holloway’s interest in Zeta 2 Reticuli
> has proven to be mutually beneficial. While the good doctors rely on
> ancient carvings and primitive cave paintings, **my science division’s
> own long range scans have recently detected a faint, almost
> imperceptible signal emanating from one of the lesser moons in that
> system. And contrary to the findings of Shaw and Holloway, which
> target LV-223 as our primary site of interest, our findings suggest
> the point of origin could actually be the moon LV-426.**
>
> Per standard procedure, we will embed a David 8 unit with the crew.
> and he will be programmed with multiple contingency plans to address
> and exploit whatever assets we secure on 223. But only David will know
> about 426 and will ensure that the rest of the crew- including
> Meredith – learn nothing about the transmission we’ve recently
> discovered until the time is right.
>
> For if Yutani’s new ECIU software is to be trusted, there might be
> great risk awaiting us on the path to an even greater reward.

Comment: If they knew about the signal in 2078 or 2079, why did they wait more than forty years to investigate it?

Comment: @Sagierian - Good question.

Comment: Pretty fast for a company that size. Imagine all the meetings and VPs they had to get buy-in from